# Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to build a jni project which generates a shared library using the Android-ndk.
I'm going to code a some part in assembly language as needed, so I configured the project as the following.

```
Android.mk:
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE    := my_test
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Test.cpp MyAsm.s
    LOCAL_CFLAGS := 
    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Application.mk:
    APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
    APP_STL := stlport_static

Test.cpp:
    ...

    MyAsmFunc();

    ...
MyAsm.s:
    .text
    .align  2
    .global MyAsmFunc
    MyAsmFunc:
        ...
        tbb [PC,R1]
        ...
        cbnz R1,loc_51ACE
        ...
```

When I was compiling the project, I've got the following error msg.

```
MyAsm.s:224: Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode `tbb [PC,R1]'
MyAsm.s:882: Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode `cbnz R1,loc_51ACE'
```

My question is how to build the project successful. Help me, please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cjaghefc.html),

```
These 16-bit Thumb instructions are available in ARMv6T2 and above.
There are no ARM or 32-bit Thumb versions of these instructions.
```

You're compiling for ARMv7-A, so the first part is fine.  However, it's trying to interpret the instructions as ARM rather than THUMB/THUMB2.  Add `.thumb` / `.thumb_func` directives to your assembly source file to set THUMB mode.  See also the [GNU as docs](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.17/as/ARM-Directives.html#ARM-Directives).